# For a Single Page Application: ExpressJS or Restify or both?

Tags: rest, node.js, express

I'm working with NodeJS + Mongoose, writing a Single Page Application, so I need to serve some statics and then all the interaction between frontend and backend is done via XHR. Eventually I'm thinking about writing a native mobile app accessing the same backend. Is there any  pattern / best practice I should apply here?, I thought that I may need to extract the API to be exposed via Restify, and handle the requests from the webapp only with ExpressJS? or should I just put all the stuff exposed via Restify? I guess my confusion comes from not being worked with Restify before, so any explanation about how is it different from ExpressJS (specially when talking about a Single Page App) is really welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I am implementing a similar solution, mobile app & website with expressjs and backbonejs. I did not use restify because i did not think i needed the extra complexity, there were not that many API endpoints so expressjs handled everything ok for me.

BTW take a look at this post on restify performance, I just saw it today and have not personally validate the contents.

Benchmarking APIs using PerfectAPI vs Express.js vs Restify.js « « PerfectAPI Blog PerfectAPI Blog http://bit.ly/xrTguB

Comment: Ok then, if you reach eventually a point of enough complexity which can differentiate your webapp from your API then you might need to consider the extra work. BTW, thanks for the link, I never heard about PerfectAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Restify is packaging DTrace and various handlers that Express doesn't. If you just have one API endpoint and don't need DTrace, it doesn't make sense to run Restify.

Also, you might want to try [express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource)

Comment: express-resource is a good recommendation. Thanks for the link. I hadn't heard of it.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR - If your use-case is basic enough that you require a handful of simple RESTful endpoints, you might want to stick to Node....but, that's my personal preference to stay lean on dependencies.